# Tensorflow While loop error

Tags: python, tensorflow

Not Sure why my code not working. The code below generate error:

```
ValueError: Initializer for variable while_7/Variable/ is from inside a control-flow construct, such as a loop or conditional. When creating a variable inside a loop or conditional, use a lambda as the initializer.
```

Need a quick fix on this loop..
For each tf.while_loop, with index "i". if the minimum value of distance matrix dist[,i] <= caliper then output the first min value index; i.e. (y,i). Then set dist[y,]=[None, None, None, None].
Given the example matix "myx","myy";
The while loop should output match pair indx [[0,None],[1,5],[2,4],[3,None]]

```
import math
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

myx=np.array([2.4,0.2,0.5,1.6])
myy=np.array([10.1,3.2,7.5,8.6,1,0.1,11,18])

Xxx=np.transpose(np.repeat(myx[:, np.newaxis], myy.size , axis=1))
Yyy=np.repeat(myy[:, np.newaxis], myx.size , axis=1)

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, shape=(myy.size,myx.size))
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, shape=(myy.size,myx.size))
# define a caliper 
calp=tf.constant(0.5,tf.float64)

with tf.device('/cpu:0'):

    dist = tf.abs(tf.subtract(X,Y))

    # Use an explicit shape for `i`.
    i = tf.placeholder(dtype='int64', shape=[])

    # Add a second unused argument to `condition()`.
    def condition(i, *arg):
        return i <= myx.size-1
    # Add a second unused argument to `b()`.
    def b(i, temp_pr, _):

        tfslic = dist[0:myy.size, i]

    # Drop the `axis` argument from `tf.reduce_min()`
    minVal=tf.reduce_min(tfslic)

    y = tf.cond(
        tf.less_equal(minVal, calp),
        # Reshape the output of `tf.argmin()` to be a scalar.
        lambda: tf.argmin(tfslic, 0),
        # Explicitly convert the false-branch value to `tf.int64`.
        lambda: tf.constant(99999, dtype=tf.int64))
        ### Need to drop the matched one ###
        #newdist=tf.stack([dist[0:y], dist[y:myx.size-1]])
        ### Need to save every match 2 dim

    '''
    :::::::::::::PROBLEM START HERE:::::::::::
    For each tf.while_loop, with index "i"
    if the minimum value of distance matrix dist[,i] <= caliper
    then output the first min value index. i.e. (y,i)

    Then set dist[y,]=[None, None, None, None]   

    Given the example matix "myx","myy";
    The while loop should output match pair indx [[0,None],[1,5],[2,4],[3,None]]
    '''
    varDist=tf.Variable(temp_pr)

    temp_af = tf.cond(
        tf.less_equal(minVal, calp),
        lambda: tf.assign(varDist[y,],[9999.,9999.,9999.,9999.]),
        lambda: tf.Variable(dist))


    return i+1, y, temp_af

# Add a dummy initial value for the second loop variable.
# Rename the first return value to `i_out` to avoid clashing with `i` above.
i_out, r, dist= tf.while_loop(condition, b, [i, dist, tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.int64)])
#mypair=tf.stack([i_out-1,r],0)

sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
dmat = sess.run(dist, feed_dict={X:Xxx, Y: Yyy,i:0})
sess.close()

print(dmat)
```